# Get URL value from string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how can I extract a URL from the following string in JS.

```
var str = '[velocity type="youtube" id="239793212" img="http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/image-placeholder.jpg" alt="Play" color="#FFFFFF" bkg_color="transparent"]';
```

I would like to somehow pull only the `http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/image-placeholder.jpg` value from this WordPress shortcode which is being read by the WordPress TinyMCE editor.

I should add that the string will not always be in the exact format and the position of `img=""` will fluctuate.

Is there a way to parse this string as JSON or an array so I can access the value of `img`?

Comment: You should have tagged your question with regex. That would help you to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/img="([^"]*)"/.exec(str)[1]
```

In English: Create a regular expression that matches the `img` part, put the URL in group 1 and after executing the expression on the string, get the contents of group 1.

The expression breaks down as

```
img="        # the string 'img="'
(            # begin group 1
  [^"]*      #   any character that is not a '"', any number of times
)            # end group 1
"            # the final double quote
```

Relevant documentation: [`RegExp.prototype.exec()` on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and of course the primary info site on regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Answer (score 1):

A not so OO way to do it:

```
var str = '[velocity type="youtube" id="239793212" img="http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/image-placeholder.jpg" alt="Play" color="#FFFFFF" bkg_color="transparent"]';

var url = null;
str.split(' ').forEach(function(s){
  if(s.indexOf('img') > -1) {
    url = s.split("=")[1]
  }
})
// url now contains your url
console.log(url);
```

Or as a one liner:

```
var url = str.split(' ').filter(function(s){ return s.indexOf('img') > -1})[0].split("=")[1]
```

Comment: Nope, that'd give him `"the url"`. ;)

Comment: It's not giving you the pure URL. It's enclosed by `"`. You just split by `=` but don't remove the `"`.

Comment: Oh, I see! Sorry :S Just add a `.replace('"','')` then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is a Regular Expression.

```
var regEx= /"http:\/\/.+?"/g; //If you want to extract all urls.
var imgEx= /img=".+?"/g // If you want to extract all img parameters.
```